# Checking if an input is within its range of limits in C++

Tags: c++, input, limits

I need to create multiple functions that will check if an input is valid or not.
Here are some of my codes:

```
bool IsValidRange(signed char s)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    if (!((s>=SCHAR_MIN)&&(s<=SCHAR_MAX)))
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}

bool IsValidRange(int s)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    if (!((s>=INT_MIN)&&(s<=INT_MAX)))
    {
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

I'm using the header limits.h for this. Am I doing this the right way? Please take note that I'm just a beginner. I hope you all will understand. Thank you!

Comment: Those functions could never return false.  By definition, an int can never fall outside the range INT_MIN:INT_MAX.  Also, `return v >= min && v <= max`;  No need for so many lines.

Comment: @EdS. Is there any way I can accomplish this? I'll try your code. Thanks!

Comment: Well, think about it. How could an int possibly fall outside INT_MIN-INT_MAX?  What number would that be exactly?  Those constants represent the lower and upper bounds of an int.

Comment: @EdS. Argh, looks like you beat me to it by a good 2 minutes. I hate being so slow at typing english. :(

Comment: @syam: Meh, no problem, spread the (rep) wealth I say.

Comment: @EdS. Well, actually I am required to create a code that will check if the input is in range. For example, if I enter '!' on an input that requires an int input, the function should react BUT what they want me to do is to check if that number is within the range. I know this is somewhat blurry but I hope you'll get the point.

Comment: Well this is the wrong way to do it.  The integral value of the character `!` is within the range of an int.  You have misunderstood the assignment.  You want an `is_numeric(char)` type function or you want to check a smaller range.

Answer (score 6):

the template above will not work for the mixture of signed and unsigned types, in addition to floats.

```
template<typename RangeType, typename ValueType >
bool IsInRange( ValueType value ) 
{
    if( ! numeric_limits<RangeType>::is_integer )
    {
        return  (value > 0 ? value  : -value) <= numeric_limits<RangeType>::max(); 
    }

    if ( numeric_limits<RangeType>::is_signed == 
         numeric_limits<ValueType>::is_signed )
    {
        return value >= numeric_limits<RangeType>::min() &&
               value <= numeric_limits<RangeType>::max();
    }
    else if( numeric_limits<RangeType>::is_signed )
    {
        return value <= numeric_limits<RangeType>::max();
    }
    else
    {
        return value >= 0 && value <=  numeric_limits<RangeType>::max();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Perhaps, under the first `if`, the `return` statement should be extended with `|| (std::isinf(value) && numeric_limits<RangeType>::has_infinity)`

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately it doesn't suppress the compiler warnings about sign change on integer conversions. Also in my opinion it works for `mixture of signed and unsigned types` in contrast to what you write. That mixture problem was why I was Googling.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need all those convolutions with booleans. Just return the expression directly:

```
return (s >= SCHAR_MIN) && (s <= SCHAR_MAX);
```

Second, you should realize that both your functions always yield `true`: by definition, a `signed char` is always in the range `[SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX]`, and an `int` is always in the range `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`.

But if you chose different bounds, this would indeed be the way to do it (taking into account my first remark).

As **EdS.** suggested, you could use a templated solution to reduce the number of functions/overloads you need:

```
template<class T>
bool check_range(T value, T min, T max) {
    return (value >= min) && (value <= max);
}
```

Comment: @syam How do I do that "different bounds"? I think that is the one that I want to accomplish...

Comment: @syam And oh, If I enter an int that is more than 2147483647 will it possible return false? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy Well, you seem to confuse the string representation of a number (eg. `"123"` which is just a sequence of 3 characters) and the "native" representation of integers that computers handle internally (eg. 4 bytes for an `int` on many platforms). If `int` is 4 bytes on your platform, then you *can't* have an `int` greater than 2147483647 (INT_MAX) , that's simply impossible. I suspect you might want to use [`strtol` and friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: @syam Is there any possible way I can get the bytes that an input is placed then compare it to the INT_MAX? Thanks!

Comment: @Christian No offence intended, but it looks like you're missing some very basic concepts here (especially when looking at your questions history, which all revolve around the same theme). My best advice would be to discuss it with your teacher so that (s)he can clear any misunderstandings you may be facing. SO is not really the right place to get explanations on such basic topics (questions that don't show a *minimal understanding of the problem being solved* are off-topic here, harsh as it may sound it is the rules of the house). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <limits>

template<typename ValueType, typename RangeType >
bool IsInRange( ValueType value ) {
    return (value >= numeric_limits<RangeType>::min()) &&
           (value <= numeric_limits<RangeType>::max());
}
```

This will work for integral data types except for floating point values. `numeric_limits<T>::min()` will return the minimum normalized **positive** value for floating point types. C++11 introduced `numeric_limits<T>::lowest()` to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try this out with `IsInRange< int16_t, uint32_t >` it will fail and also give a compiler warning explaining why: `warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign`

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation based on the answer by RadioKat, but it suppresses compiler warnings like:

```
warning: pointless comparison of unsigned integer with zero
warning: integer conversion resulted in a change of sign
```

by using template meta programming:

```
#include <limits>

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value, bool T_RangeSigned, bool T_ValueSigned >
struct InIntegerRange;

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value >
struct InIntegerRange< T_Range, T_Value, false, false >
{
    bool operator()( T_Value const & x )
    {
        return x >= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::min() &&
               x <= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::max();
    }
};

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value >
struct InIntegerRange< T_Range, T_Value, false, true >
{
    bool operator()( T_Value const & x )
    {
        return x >= 0 && x <= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::max();
    }
};

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value >
struct InIntegerRange< T_Range, T_Value, true, false >
{
    bool operator()( T_Value const & x )
    {
        return x <= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::max(); /* x >= 0 is given */
    }
};

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value >
struct InIntegerRange< T_Range, T_Value, true, true >
{
    bool operator()( T_Value const & x )
    {
        return x >= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::min() &&
               x <= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::max();
    }
};

template< typename T_Range, typename T_Value >
inline bool inRange( T_Value const & x )
{
    if( std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::is_integer )
    {
        return InIntegerRange< T_Range, T_Value,
                               std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::is_signed,
                               std::numeric_limits< T_Value >::is_signed >()( x );
    }
    else
    {
        return ( x > 0 ? x : -x ) <= std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::max() ||
               ( std::isnan(x) && std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::has_quiet_NaN ) ||
               ( std::isinf(x) && std::numeric_limits< T_Range >::has_infinity );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. If you define the function's argument as a specific type, then the compiler forces the input in the declared type's range limits.

So your code always returns the true, and the checking process practically is not working.

For solving this kind of problem, You can use a simple technique. How? Let me explain: You can choose an argument with limits larger than the actual value you decided.
For example: if the argument is an integer, define it as a long type.

Now, your checking process will work. Why?

Because the number you declared can accept the more considerable value, but you will finally decide how much the input value should be in the checking process.

**This trick can be expensive in compilation and memory usage, and it is slightly slippery for the novice. But for non-complex functions and procedures and the limited number of arguments or variables work well.**

Check the following code in your computer and see the result:

```
long i = 0L;
int left_limit = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int right_limit = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
std::cin >> i;
if (i < left_limit || i > right_limit) {
        std::cout << "You have reached to out of limits." << std::endl;
        return false;
}
```